# MySQL - IF statement with NOT IN before SELECT

Tags: mysql

Attempting to do an `IF` conditional before a `SELECT`. There is an error on the `IF` line but not sure what it is:

```
...
INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog3 ON po2.program_outcome_group_fk = pog3.program_outcome_group_pk
UNION ALL
    IF(pog3.program_outcome_group_pk NOT IN (10,11,12,13,14)){
    SELECT ...
```

Comment: please provide data set and expected result. You can use case statement with this id in WHERE clause. If not this id select query return result else no data

Comment: It's a syntax error 1064 on the IF line.  Does the pog3 alias go out of scope after the UNION ALL, or is it something else?

Comment: UNION requires SELECT statements or derived tables on its `left` and `right` side - you can not prepend an IF to the SELECT statement.

Comment: Makes sense.  There is however another SELECT after the IF conditional, and that SELECT is not conditional...